# Prove $f(y) = y$ for all real numbers $y$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(q)=q$ for every rational number $q$. Prove $f(y) = y$ for every real number $y$.

I would like to prove this with sequences. I know that every irrational number (or real number) is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers. I am just not sure how to apply this to prove $f(y) = y$ for all $y$ a real number.

Comment: $f$ being continuous at $y$ means $\displaystyle \lim_{x_n\to y} f(x_n) = f \left(\lim_{x_n \to y} x_n \right)$.

Comment: OP: You should type this as a new question in a new post.

Comment: Please do not change the question after an answer is posted.

Answer (score 4):

For each real number $r$ can be the limit of a sequence of rational numbers $r_n$. Thus $r_n \to r\implies f(r_n) \to f(r),  r_n  \to r$, and $f(r_n) = r_n$. Thus $r = f(r)$.

In regard to the newly stated question, the answer is "yes" because $f$ is lipschitz, hence is uniformly continuous.

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: OP changed the question.